# How to position div on left side of screen pushing all content to the right

Tags: html, css

I am experimenting with a few things and I have a navbar that I want to switch from up to to the left side of the screen. I am able to position a basic div to the left side of the screen but what I would like to do is have it push all content on the right of it so that I can implement a hide feature to the menu.

**CSS**

```
div {
    position: absolute; // also tried fixed
    left: 0px;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100px;
    background: #222222;
    top: 0px;
    bottom: 0px
}
```

As you can see in the image the div is just on the left side but the content is just over lapping it. Any way to push the content to the right after the div? Any help would be awesome.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Put your right content in a container and then give it `margin-left` equal to the width of the left column. So:

HTML

```
<div id='right'>
    <!-- all your left right elements go in here -->
</div>
```

CSS

```
#right { margin-left: 200px; /* or whatever */ }
```

Comment: It worked but now it pushed my content on the right side off screen, any way to adjust that?

Comment: I think I got this man, thanks for pointing me in the right direction